# Maintaining relationship and history in mysql databases

Tags: mysql, database

I am designing a mysql database and have come across these relations which will grow in the future.

Suppose Customer is tied to 2 different tables **Policies** and **Options**.

Each customer has multiple relationship with policies and likewise with options. Since I am keeping a details and history of the table as well every time I add a relation with customer, I will have to maintain another 2 tables. To calculate the price the customer owes, I will have to go thru customer_policies then customer_options and calculate the total price. Also the number of tables increases as the relationship increases.

- If customer has a relation with policies it will have 2 tables -
  customer_policies and customer_policies_details.
- If customer has one more relation with options, it will add 3 more -
  customer_options, and customer_option_history.
- Like wise, it will keep on adding 2 more tables if there is one more
  relation and the problem grows and grows.

I have tried 2 different options which I have mentioned below. I wanted to know what is the best way to solve this problem so that the table can be maintained as the relation grows.

**Option 1:**

customer_policies:

```
CustomerPolicyId CustomerId PolicyId Status
1                1          1        Active 
2                1          2        Active
```

customer_policies_details:

```
CustomerPolicyDetailsId CustomerPolicyId Price
1                       1                10   
2                       2                20
```

customer_options:

```
CustomerOptionId CustomerId OptionId Status
1                1          1        Active 
2                1          2        Active
```

customer_options_details:

```
CustomerOptionDetailsId CustomerOptionId Price
1                       1                10   
2                       2                20
```

**Option 2:**

Create a single table customer_selections and use Type and Id field instead like so:

customer_selections:

```
CustomerSelctionId  CustomerId  Type    Id Status
1                   1           Policy  1  Active
2                   1           Policy  2  Active
3                   1           Option  1  Active
4                   1           Option  2  Active
```

customer_selection_details:

```
DetailsId  CustomerSelctionId  Price   
1           1                  10  
2           2                  20  
3           3                  10  
4           4                  20
```

To create a history of this I just have to create a customer_selections_details and keep track of all changes.

There should be better ways to solve this problem.

Comment: This is a question of normalization.  Do you expect to very frequently join the policy and details together?

Comment: Yes . To get poliicies and options opted by users and joins have to be done frequently.

Comment: If you expect _very_ frequent joins, and high peformance is a concern, then you might want to use option 2.  Otherwise, I would go for option 1.